# Unterminated string constant error in ASP.NET Razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC Web application and at the top of one of my razor pages i have this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("@TempData["alertMessage"]");
    </script>
```

If I understand the error

> Unterminated string constant

correctly, it means I haven't closed the quotation marks. But if I look at the code it should be closed correctly right?

What is wrong about it?

Comment: `alert("@(TempData["alertMessage"])");`

Comment: This also seems to remove the error, so there's multiple correct answers. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping JavaScript string literals in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470887/escaping-javascript-string-literals-in-views)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `single` quotes in order to avoid the `error`.

```
alert('@TempData["alertMessage"]');
```

With the other words you should wrap the statement within single `quotes`.

Comment: Ahhhh that fixed it for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't address the core problem which is differentiating between Razor code and HTML/JS code. Using an explicit `@(...)` does it well.

Comment: @haim770, thanks for your point. This problem can appear, for instance,  when you append dynamically elements to page which contains attributes and you're forces to use `single` quotes.

Comment: This will HTML-encode the string that must be JS-encoded. Please use the [correct approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233067/11683) instead.