# Escaping paragraph does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have below JavaScript function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if('@TempData["Message"]' != "") {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

It just opens a modal with `TempData`.

I populate that `TempData` from backend like:

```
res.Error = string.Join<string>("\\n ", errores);
TempData["Message"]  = res.Error;
```

So for each `res.Error` it adds an escaped new line (`\\n`)

When I debug application with Chrome, `TempData` does not transform to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if('Error1\nError2\nError3\nError executed' != "") {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Instead it receives something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if('Error1
                Error2
                Error3
                Error executed' != "") {
                $("#myModal").modal();
            }
        })
```

How can I escape this string correctly?

As per comment below I tried to use `Environment.NewLine` as:

```
res.Error = string.Join<string>(Environment.NewLine, errores);
```

But now JavaScript throws an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

JavaScript Output:

```
  <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
                if ('Error1
                     Error2
                     Error3' != "") {
           $("#myModal").modal();
         }
    });
        </script>
```

Why is there a JavaScript syntax error?

[image: ErrorImage]

Comment: It appears as though English is not your first language and further, that perhaps your first language is Spanish. If so, it might go easier if you posted on [es.so].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping JavaScript string literals in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470887/escaping-javascript-string-literals-in-views)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to put a list of string into a string, you can use this:

```
String.join(Environment.NewLine, errores)
```

And if you are using this data to only perform checks(if data exists in you list), it's better to use a single value which will help you doing it in a more simplified way

Comment: I try it but now I get Javascript error syntax  (I update my question) with problem

Comment: What is the main purpose of the value res.Error? Will you be using the value only for the comparison? And what is the type of res.Error?

Comment: Yes, when it comes different to null , it show bootstrap modal with string error, but now it dont show it because JavaScript have syntax error

Comment: Are you certain that it is IF statement causing the error? Or the call to open the modal? Try adding "alert(1);" before and within the if statement and see what happens

Comment: Yes I’m sire, because if I only receive Error1 it runs correctly,but if I receive more than 1 (with escaping) I receive syntax error

Comment: Then try this:   if('@Html.Raw(TempData["Message"])' != '')

Comment: Same error. I uploaded photo of chrome debug, it's like JS don't get string after NewLine

Comment: Looks like its because its still rendering the value on multiple lines. Either return a single value(bool) from your backend to specify of the value has data or not. Or perform the comparison in Razor: If(@!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["Message"]). Let me know if thi works