# How to pass the string in original format to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, resx

I have a Javascript function below, which takes a label defined in resx.file...
Label is something like: **Success from customer's price list.**

```
enter code here: $(function () {
    systemadminhourlyrateindex().init(
        '@Html.Raw(Label.SuccessDeleteIsDelegated)' //At this point label is as origin.
    );
});
```

But when I try to use it in JS function, it dose not escape the single quote from customer's correctly. Instead it adds wierd chars something into the word customers. So it becomes something like *customer---s*
where --- is & # 3 9; Maybe this is ascii for single quote?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470887/escaping-javascript-string-literals-in-views ?

Comment: Or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Just guessing, but could it be that it's not a normal single-quote `'`, but some unicode character that looks like a single-quote?

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me.

@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(YouLabel)